# How to kill a running php script in windows

Tags: php

I have a php script running in an infinite loop that I need killed without restarting apache.

I have access to the server via remote desktop. Please advise.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Find the running scripts you want to kill:

```
tasklist /v | find "php"
```

Make note of the process ID, kill it with:

```
taskkill /PID 3776
```

Same as doing:

```
ps aux | grep php

kill 3776
```

Comment: Btw any idea how to implement this semi automated? So if I enter the filename, it kills the script? But it works perfectly if I follow your steps manually in the command line

Comment: In my case, there is no separate process for PHP. It is running its infinite loop under the Apache server (httpd.exe). I don't want to kill the server process, just signal PHP to stop running. Unlike Linux, Windows doesn't have a "signal" command.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

Windows task manager->Processes->apache ?

It should be there, simply end the process.

**EDIT -**

Just saw that you don't want to kill apache.

I'm not sure that's possible, as PHP runs as an apache module I believe.

Comment: OP said: `without restarting apache`

Comment: wouldn't that kill apache too? I don't think there's a way just to have impact on the php

Answer (score 0):

In the task manager look for the apache "fork" that takes 100% of the CPU, then kill it.

Comment: There is no such fork when PHP runs as an Apache module. Normally, Apache runs two processes on my local computer. When PHP is in an infinite loop, one of those processes takes 13% of the "cpu" instead of 0%. PHP needs a way to interrupt it from outside (perhaps with an exception) when a program misbehaves. Note that set_time_limit() can't be used when the processing could take an amount of time that cannot be predicted in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/229435/how-to-break-from-infinite-loop-caused-by-php-script-running-as-root

For future, make sure to have some secure file lock for the script:

```
while(true)  //script loop
{
   if(file_exists("STOP")) {
     unlink("STOP");
     exit;
   }
   /*Do some work*/
```

}

Comment: Tried that in the command line and it says 'pkill' is not a recognised command?

Comment: Is your system linux or windows? If it is linux, you can see running php process for every one running PHP script (if the server is configured correctly). I also found [this function](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php) that might help you.