# Ultimate Kill for Ruby Script

Tags: ruby, windows

I have an unstoppable Ruby script that I need to be able to stop. Here is the following code:

```
require 'win32ole'

wsh = WIN32OLE.new("WScript.Shell")

def fileToArray(file)
    x = []
    File.foreach("#{file}") do |line|
        x << line.to_s.split('')
    end
    return x.flatten!
end
tests = fileToArray("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\x\\Script\\includes\\classes.php")

sleep 10
x = 0
y = tests.length
while x <= y do
    send = tests[x]
    speed = 0.025
    if x == y
        print "Test Complete"
        break()
    #You guys don't need to see this code, it's just detecting what keys are 
    #in the array and reading them to the file. But important to know that it is incrementing based on sent keys
    else
        x += 1
    end
end
```

My problem is that the classes.php it is reading from is 4,000 lines long and takes a long time to get through. If it messes up, I have to wait until it is finished. There is no way for me to stop this loop from running until it is finished unless I completely log out from everything, `CTRL+ALT+DEL` Option: `Logout`. I've tried `curses` I've tried `gets` on `exit`. `CTRL^C` doesn't work either. I'd much rather have a written in solution, but otherwise I wouldn't mind knowing a few keys to killswitch the process a.k.a. "Kill it, kill it with keys"

Comment: have you tried ctrl+shift+esc ten `kill process tree` inside process manager?

Comment: It continues to run, so I can't even access the Task Manager without it jumping all over the menu options

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14686531/5006469)?

Comment: @standelaune did I see what? That it went psycho on my Task Manager? Oh yeah, that's why I forced a log out.

Comment: Why not just make it so your program can be stopped by the user with e.g. Ctrl+C? That's what `trap` is for. http://timuruski.net/blog/2014/signals-traps-and-rescues/

Comment: You miss the link. I'm not sure to understand your problem anyway. Does `Ctrl+Pause/Break` work ?

Comment: @Jordan Reading now, will get back to you.

Comment: @standelaune `CTRL+Pause` did not work

Comment: @Jordan tested in code, did not work. Will test it in terminal when it is finished cycling through.

Comment: @Jordan tested it in terminal, did not work

Comment: When writing Ruby, try to use the proper naming convention. That method should be called `file_to_array`. Capital letters often have significant meaning, so case is something to pay attention to.

Comment: @tadman when did Ruby move away from Camel Casing?

Comment: @TommyMertell Ruby's been advocating `ClassName`, `method_or_variable_name` and `CONSTANT_NAME` for a while now, at least ten years. Pretty much every style guide advocates this.

Comment: @tadman ah, okay. I will keep that in mind in future development.

Answer (score 0):

You read each byte in an array, how long does your array get if you let in run till the end ? Filling an array of hundreds of thousands takes a long time indeed. Should see the rest of your code to decide if there is no better way, and why the win32ole object ?

If the standard windows keys to interrupt the jog don't word (Ctrl-c or Ctrl-break) and you can't use taskmanager, surely the console will still be responsive.

Here a script that does what you do. I put it in an endless loop so that I have to terminate it. The Process.pid shows the process id. 
In advance you open a console and when you want to terminate the script you enter the following

```
taskkill /f /pid 5532
```

The /f is for forcing to terminate, the number is the pid you get from your script

```
# encoding:utf-8
STDOUT.sync = true
s1 = File.read __FILE__
puts Process.pid
class String
    def to_a
      while true # endless loop just for testing the kill
        each_byte.inject([]){|result, char| result << char}
      end
    end
end

p s1.to_a
```

Tested with Windows 7 and Ruby MRI 1.9.3

EDIT:
based on your comment here another way to send keys to a program
If I understand correctly what you want to do you also don't need to split the string in advance.

```
require 'win32ole'
#for this script Autoit3 must be installed

s1 = "a string of thousands of characters"

# activate the correct window with the appclass
ai.Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 4)
appClass = "[CLASS:xxxxxxxx]"    # retrieved with AutoIt Window Info 
ai = WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")
ai.WinActivate(appClass)

# or with the handle
handle = "[HANDLE:#{ai.wingethandle(appClass)}]" 
ai.WinActivate(handle)

# send keys, controlkeys or words to the program
ai.Send('{HOME}') #you can send control keys like that

s1.each_byte{|char| ai.Send(char); sleep 1} #to send everything char after char

s1[0..10].each_byte{|char| ai.Send(char); sleep 1} #to send the first 10 chars
```

Comment: The purpose of the program is to simulate typing. This is why I use the win32ole library as it allows me to send keys to a file and control the speed.

Comment: i see, you use sendkeys ? i might have a better solution for that.. but then there is an even better solution for your array problem, i'll add it to my answer

Comment: I wasn't aware I had an array problem. I'm switching the code to a case statement to make it a little faster but here is a link to the actual code.  https://github.com/sinithwar/LazyProjects/blob/master/RubyTypingSimulator.rb

Comment: checked your script, you read in a very big char array and use just 1000 first chars, see my last code sample, if you don't want to use AutoIt (I really recommend it) then at least use the solution for sending the chars